# ReactJS, componentWillReceiveProps can get data, but render cannot

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a ReactJS 15 project using sagas and reselect as middle ware to fetch data. I can successfully get data in **componentWillReceiveProps** and set the data in the state, however there still not data in the render function first run when I take the data from the state. Anyone knows what's going on here? BTW, I used [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)   as mock data server.Below is part of my code:

Component:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timelineData: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // use react redux to make the api call here
    this.props.fetchTimelineData({
      id: parse(this.props.location.search.substr(1)).id,
    });
  }
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('nextProps', nextProps);
    // Successfully take the data from the nextProps (timelineData is not [])
    const { timelineData } = nextProps;
    this.setState({
      timelineData,
    });
  }

render() {
    // the first render called timelineData is an empty array, which will not able to populate the UI
    // which RaiseTimeline is empty
    const { timelineData } = this.state;
    return (
      <RaiseTimelineStyled>
        <RaiseDetailsGrid>
          <Accordion
            title={
              <RaiseAccordionHeader image={image} title={'Timeline'} />
          }>
            <Timeline.wrapper>
              <RaiseTimelineStyled.divider>
                <RaiseTimelineStyled.container>
                  <RaiseTimeline timelineEvents={timelineData} />
```

action.js (works fine):

```
export const setTimelineData = timelineData => console.log('actions.js', timelineData) || ({
  type: ACTIONS.SET_TIMELINE_DATA,
  timelineData,
});
```

Api.js (works fine):

```
class TimelineAPI {
  // payload will be used after backend done
  static fetchTimelineData(payload) {
    return http.get(`${baseURI}/timeline`).then(result => console.log('api', result.data) || result.data);
  }
}
```

Reducers: (works fine)

```
function TimelineDataReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.SET_TIMELINE_DATA:
      console.log('reducer', action.timelineData);
      return state.set('numbers', action.timelineData);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Sagas: (works fine)

```
export function* fetchTimelineData(action) {
  yield put(togglePendingScreen(true));

  const { result, error } = yield call(TimelineAPI.fetchTimelineData, action.payload);

  if (error) {
    yield put(
      toggleErrorModal({
        isOpen: true,
        text: error.code,
        source: 'Fetch Timeline Data',
      }),
    );
  } else {
    console.log('Sagas', result.timeline);
    yield put(ACTIONS.setTimelineData(result.timeline));
  }
  yield put(togglePendingScreen(false));
}
```

Selectors(works fine):

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectTimelineData = state => state.get('TimelinePageData').toJS();

const selectTimeline = () =>
  createSelector(selectTimelineData, TimelineDataState => TimelineDataState.numbers);

export { selectTimeline };
```

Comment: Can you try with  `this.setState({
      timelineData:[...timelineData]
    });` in componentWillReceiveProps ?

Comment: You can simply use conditional rendering to only render the component when `timelineData` is truthy and has length or default to an empty array.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated, you should prefer using `componentDidUpdate` and **adding a condition** before updating the state : `if(prevProps.timelineData !== this.props.timelineData){this.setState(...)}` to prevent infinite re-render

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems logical that you have no data on the first run.

The reason is there **render() function is called once before the componentDidMount()** in the react life cycle. (V15)

Look here for the react 15 life cycle : https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/923dffb2cd9504ee440791fade8db5f9

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, everything is correct, but another person name but another person name same component and set its state in side the constructor, so it's not able to render in the first time